# The good 3D GUI engine

Tags: wpf, user-interface, 3d-engine

I know WPF is one of good 3D GUI engine, but I want to know other good 3D GUI engines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XNA comes with a 3D GUI engine. It is targeted for games, but it may be used for other purposes as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Flash Player 10](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/features/) allows any GUI to be rotated and scaled in 3D.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux there is [Compiz Fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz_Fusion) which is an X11 implementation on top of OpenGL. I believe the GUI system in MacOSX and iPhone is OpenGL based ([Quartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(graphics_layer))).

If you are referring to GUI frameworks that support 3D I think most will, ie from [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/opengl.html) to [Qt](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/opengl-hellogl.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have done some [Papervision3D](http://papervision3d.org/) on Flash / ActionScript.

And it is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

[Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) is a direct competitor to WPF.